# Preventing Eclipse from making suggestions that would alter a certain file

Tags: java, eclipse, code-generation

Is there a way of forcing Eclipse not to come with auto-correct changes that would alter the current file I am in?

Usage scenario:
I have a script that automatically generates a .java file, which contains references to undefined methods, that I then use Ctrl+1 to generate stubs for. However, Eclipse also occasionally suggests "change to ..." in addition to "create method ...". Is there a way of forcing Eclipse to never make that suggestion for a particular file?

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot modify/extend the script to create the stub methods as well? Only really suggesting this as I don't *think* there will be a way to turn this off per file in eclipse.

Comment: That would in my case be quite complicated indeed.